# Series solution of an ODE (taylor series, infinite series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

We have the ODE:

$$y' = -3y$$

Assume that the solution of the ODE can be written as a Taylor series in the form:

$$y(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots + a_nx^n + \ldots$$

Using this infinite series, find an equation that relates $a_{n+1}$ to $a_n$

From that result, deduce the coefficients $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n$ in terms of $a_0$.

I have tried substituting $y(x)$ as well as the derivative of $y(x)$ into the ODE but am unsure what to do next to relate $a_{n+1}$ to $a_n$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

I think the answer to the first part is (correct me if I'm wrong) :

$$a_{n+1} = -\frac{3a_n}{n+1}$$

I then used this to find the first few terms ($a_1,a_2,a_3$ etc.) but can't seem to figure out the second part of the problem (deduce the coefficients $a_n$ in terms of $a_0$)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you include your substitution of the series into the ODE?

Comment: I had done: a1 + 2*a2*x + 3*a3*x^2 + .... = -3(a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + ...)

Comment: This is a functional equation: it must hold for any $x$. Can you see a way to use this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand how that can help

Comment: This tells you that there has to be an equality for the coefficients in front of each power of $x$, because if $a_0 +a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +... = 0 $ for all $x$, this means that $a_0=0$, $a_1=0$, $a_2=0$ etc.

Comment: Okay, have had a think and came up with this: a(n+1) = -3*a(n) / (n+1)

Comment: Does that seem correct? Or am I at least on the right track?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the second part? I'm unsure where to begin.

Comment: Write your relation to derive expressions for the first few $n$ and see whether you see a pattern emerge that you can use.

Comment: Using the relation I found a1 = -3*a0,  a2 = (-3*a1)/2,  a3 = (-3*a2)/3 etc. I'm still unsure how to use this to answer the second part where express a1, a2, a3 etc in terms of just a0 though.

Comment: Compute the first few terms and notice the pattern: $a_2 = \frac{(-3)^2}{2!}a_0~~$, $a_3 = \frac{(-3)^3}{3!}a_0~~$, $a_4 = \frac{(-3)^4}{4!}a_0$, $\ldots$.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I don't really understand how you found each term. Why is the numerator raised to the power *n* and the denominator the factorial of *n*?

Comment: You can you plug in the expression for $a_1$ to find an expression for $a_2$ with just $a_0$: $a_2 = -3a_1/2 = -3 (-3a_0)/2$. Continue this and find the general relation. Winther helped you by giving the first 3 results.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've figured out how to do it now. Thanks for your help.